# Separate function for buttons created dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, html

I print this buttons with php taking info from the BBDD:

```
print "
<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 cartasdos'>
    <figure><img class='imagenEditar' height='190px' width='100%' src='../img/relatos/".$fila['imagen']."'></figure>
    <h3>".$fila['titulo']."</h3>
    <h5>".$fila['autor']."</h5>
    <h6 class='resumen'> ".$fila['sinopsis']." </h6>
    <a href='index.php?id=".$fila['id']."' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Editar</a>

   <input type='button' class='btn btn-danger borrar ' value='Borrar'>
    <a href='crud.php?id=".$fila['id']."' class='btn btn-danger si'  role='button'>Borrar</a>
    <input type='button' class='btn btn-black cancelar' value='Cancelar'>
</div>";
```

And then with jquery I want hide and show the buttons separated but when I press one of the buttons it affect to all. This is the jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".si").hide();
    $(".cancelar").hide();

    var botones=document.querySelectorAll(".borrar");

    for(i=0;i<botones.length;i++){    
        botones[i].addEventListener("click",cancelar,false);
    }
});

function cancelar(e){
    $(".si").toggle();
    $(".cancelar").toggle();
    $(e.target).toggle();

    $(".cancelar").on("click", function(){
        $(".borrar").show();
        $(".si").hide();  
        $(".cancelar").hide();
    });
}
</script>
```

How could I do it?

Comment: I dont see any of those classes in the html code you provided.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong but I've already edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it with an incremented $id, inside of the bucle that print the buttons y write the $id in the principal button and in the rest of buttons I put it in the class:

```
$id=0;
  while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
  $id++;
  print "
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 cartasdos'>
        <figure><img class='imagenEditar' height='190px' width='100%' src='../img/relatos/".$fila['imagen']."'></figure>
        <h3>".$fila['titulo']."</h3>
        <h5>".$fila['autor']."</h5>
        <h6 class='resumen'> ".$fila['sinopsis']." </h6>
        <a href='index.php?id=".$fila['id']."' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Editar</a>

        <input type='button' class='btn btn-danger borrar' id='".$id."' value='Borrar'>

        <p class='seguro ".$id."'>Ana, ¿Estás segura?</p>
        <a href='crud.php?id=".$fila['id']."' class='btn btn-danger si ".$id."'  role='button'>Borrar</a>
        <input type='button' class='btn btn-black cancelar ".$id."' value='Cancelar'>
        </div>
                ";

                }
```

And in the jquery code I take the e.target.id for the buttons with the $id in the class and e.target for the principal button with the $id in the id:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".seguro").hide();
    $(".si").hide();
    $(".cancelar").hide();

    var botones=document.querySelectorAll(".borrar");

    for(i=0;i<botones.length;i++){

        botones[i].addEventListener("click",cancelar,false);

    }

});

function cancelar(e){

    $("."+e.target.id).slideDown('slow');
    $(e.target).slideUp('slow');

    $(".cancelar").on("click", function(){

        $(e.target).slideDown('slow');
        $("."+e.target.id).slideUp('slow');

    });

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle each button with the `click()` on the selector and `toggle()` on your button e.g.:

```
$("selector").click(function(){
    $(".yourtBtn").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `$(this)` to isolate which item you want to act on. This is an example of the difference:

https://jsfiddle.net/dto07w65/1/

In your case, it might be something like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // When you click on any elements with this class
    $(".cancelar").on("click", function(){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the parent that wraps this particular clicked element
        var parent = $(this).parents('.cartasdos');
        // Once selected, show just this element
        parent.find(".borrar").show();
        // Hide all the others
        parent.find(".si").hide();
        parent.find(".cancelar").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

I am not 100% how you want your buttons to work, but his shows how to isolate using `$(this)`.